# Recalculating path's array after modification - fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

After moving, rescaling or rotating a path in fabricjs, I would like to recalculate the path's array coordinates in order to use them later to draw the exact same path on a plain HTML5 canvas.

I have gotten around rotation by storing the angle and then performing a transformation of the whole html canvas. For translation I tried recalculating the points like so:

```
point[1] = (point[1] + modifiedObject.left - oldState.left);
point[2] = (point[2] + modifiedObject.top - oldState.top);
```

but this messes up with rescaling on fabric. 
I also tried using the transformation matrix on the points, but this didn't work either and I think it's because I am missing some steps in between.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a simple demo of what I'm trying to do in essence: https://jsfiddle.net/1b68eLdr/86688/

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example to demonstrate the issue? Something runnable, if possible?

Comment: @shkaper Hey, I added a simple fiddle to it.